# Calling an external javascript function from within anythingslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, anythingslider

I've been scratching my head all morning with this one. I have some form elements contained in one of my slides. What I'm trying to do is call an external javascript function to grab the field values in order to redirect to a different URL. For example:

```
function ts_submit()
{
    var w = $('#ts_w').val();
    var p = $('#ts_p').val();
    var r = $('#ts_r').val();

    document.location = 'http://www.example.com/search/' + w + '/' + p + '/' + r;
}
```

When I call this function from the form on the slide it says the function does not exist. I'm assuming this is because the content is loaded separately from the main page but I can't work out how to get this to work.

-- EDIT --

Ignore this question, I've over complicated things by pulling in the slide content using javascript. The problem in the end was an invalid JS function name, as simple as that. Doh!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is a bit unclear, could you give us an url or a jsfiddle snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can call external Javascript function but first need to load

Something like this

```
function LoadExternalJS() {
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = '/path/to/your/external/script.js';
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
   head.appendChild(script);
 }
```

And then you can call the function ... hope it helps

Comment: Where would I need to put this function? I've tried to include the javascript function inside the slide content but it breaks anythingslider. If I could include the code directly I wouldn't have this problem. I feel like I'm missing something entirely!

Comment: You can write this in the header section and call this onLoad of body